# bindingRedirect suddenly stopped working

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm having a problem with bindingRedirect in the web.config file for a website.

These are the circumstances.  I have the 4.1.0.0 version of a third-party assembly.  I have another third-party assembly that references version 4.0.0.0 of the first assembly.  And I have a bindingRedirect in my web.config which causes 4.1.0.0 to be loaded when 4.0.0.0 is asked for.  This works in my development environment and, until 5 days ago, it worked on the hosting company's server, where the production website is.  But five days ago I started getting an error on the hosting company's server saying that version 4.1.0.0 could not be found -- in other words, suddenly my bindingRedirect was being ignored.

Since I haven't made any changes, I am assuming that something in the hosting company's environment changed.  I'm trying to work with the hosting company's tech support team, but they don't seem to completely understand bindingRedirect and the question "what changed in your environment on Saturday?" is too broad for them to answer.  Perhaps if I could pin down what sorts of changes could cause a bindingRedirect to stop working I might have a chance at getting their tech support team to dig a little more deeply on their end.

Thus, my primary question to this forum is "what could have changed in the environment that would cause the bindingRedirect to suddenly be ignored?"  Could a change to machine.config have done it?  What else could do it?  I am not [yet] asking for actions I can take on my end to make it start working again -- I need more information before I try to fix it or ask for advice.

This is the relevant portion of the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core"
                              publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked if the 4.1.0 version of the assembly is still there? Maybe they changed something and it got deleted in the process

Comment: Yes, I checked all the files.  They are as they should be.  Specifically, version 4.1.0.0 is there and the contents of the web.config file have not changed.  And then, having verified these things by eyeballing them, I went a stop further and deleted the entire contents of the folder on the server and re-uploaded all the files from a working version on my development machine.  Nothing improved.